# Vasculhar palavras na pagina e substituir

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Amigos, gostaria de saber se é possível criar um método que faça uma varredura em uma pagina html ou somente dentro de uma div, procurando uma palavra específica e substituí-la por outra palavra.

Estou tentando fazer isso, pois estou usando um plugin no meu site, e o mesmo faz propagandas, não quero vetar as propagandas, só quero ter um controle das palavras que esse plugin vai usar nas propagandas que faz.
É possivel? Agradeço desde já!

Plugin:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function(){ var widget_id = 'qZZLGGRS0H';var d=document;var w=window;function l(){
var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = '//code.jivosite.com/script/widget/'+widget_id; var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; ss.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ss);}if(d.readyState=='complete'){l();}else{if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})();</script>
```

Comment: Tens duas perguntas numa só: 1- é possivel varrer uma página e substituir conteúdo: sim, 2- é possivel substituir conteudo dentro de plugins: provavelmente não pois se forem `iframe`s há medidas de segurança do browser que impedem isso.

Comment: Dito isto ^ :Podes colocar um exemplo de plugin?

Comment: postei o plugin.
Não teria como eu mandar um método, vasculhar a pagina depois que ela for carregada, e excluir certas palavras?

Comment: Podes processar o script no lado do servidor e depois integrar na tua página, mas aí não vai ativar a estatística do anunciante...